# Eclipse SpringBoot:A child container failed to start

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I was trying to start a SpringBoot server in eclipse as well as in Spring Tool Suite and its is not working in nether of them. I get the following error  every time(A child container failed to start). I can run it from the CLI as well as from NetBean. But I want  to make it work from eclipse or from Sts. Any suggestions?

```
2017-11-08 20:05:06.114  INFO 7520 --- [           main] com.elsospring.ElsoSpringApplication     : Starting ElsoSpringApplication on DESKTOP-O3C8HCK with PID 7520 (C:\Users\elesg\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE\ElsoSpring\target\classes started by elesg in C:\Users\elesg\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE\ElsoSpring)

2017-11-08 20:05:06.114  INFO 7520 --- [           main] com.elsospring.ElsoSpringApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2017-11-08 20:05:06.167  INFO 7520 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@314c508a: startup date [Wed Nov 08 20:05:06 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy

2017-11-08 20:05:06.969  INFO 7520 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2017-11-08 20:05:06.983  INFO 7520 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2017-11-08 20:05:06.983  INFO 7520 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

2017-11-08 20:05:07.048 ERROR 7520 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2017-11-08 20:05:07.049 ERROR 7520 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.elsospring.ElsoSpringApplication.main(ElsoSpringApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2017-11-08 20:05:07.050  WARN 7520 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2017-11-08 20:05:07.053  INFO 7520 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-08 20:05:07.053 ERROR 7520 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.elsospring.ElsoSpringApplication.main(ElsoSpringApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.elsospring</groupId>
<artifactId>ElsoSpring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ElsoSpring</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please provide some more Information about your `Spring Boot` configuration, especially any beans that sets tomcat properties. Your `application.properties` and `pom.xml` files could be helpful as well.

Comment: Please use the code brackets to put your stack trace in future. Follow the proper coding format.

Comment: If you are not using Tomcat 8+ then specify a dependency for your Tomcat version (whatever it is) '<properties> <tomcat.version>7+</tomcat.version></properties>'. As Spring Boot by default takes Tomcat 8+.

Comment: I am useing Tomcat 9.0 I also provided the content of the pom.xml. The properties are empty. This is a basic Spring starterproject.

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` tells me that the Servlet 2.5 API is on the classpath but, looking at your pom, I can’t tell why. You’ve said in other comments that you are using Tomcat 9 but that stack trace shows 8.5.23. Can you double-check your dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I have tomcat 9.0.1 installed on my computer and it is working fine. As far as I know Spring tool Suit uses it's own built in tomcat isn't it ? If not how can I make it detect my installed tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same error. My Spring Boot application was starting successfully while `mvn spring-boot:run` as well as while debug `mvn spring-boot:run -X`. But while running from Eclipse it was failing and giving me this error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
_[32m :: Spring Boot :: _[39m      _[2m (v1.5.9.RELEASE)_[0;39m

_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:29.295_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mc.p.k.s.SpringKafkaWebhookApplication   _[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Starting SpringKafkaWebhookApplication on PTL009316 with PID 20952 (C:\workspace\spring-kafka-webhook\target\classes started by somnath_chakrabarti in C:\workspace\spring-kafka-webhook)
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:29.298_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mc.p.k.s.SpringKafkaWebhookApplication   _[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:29.351_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext_[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1efee8e7: startup date [Thu Dec 14 15:32:29 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.119_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mf.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor_[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.155_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker_[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb365b8a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.611_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer_[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.621_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  _[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.622_[0;39m _[32m INFO_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[           main]_[0;39m _[36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine _[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
_[2m2017-12-14 15:32:30.773_[0;39m _[31mERROR_[0;39m _[35m20952_[0;39m _[2m---_[0;39m _[2m[cat-startStop-1]_[0;39m _[36morg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  _[0;39m _[2m:_[0;39m A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_101]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_101]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
       ... 10 common frames omitted
```

But after creating a new `Spring Boot Starter project` in Eclipse and migrating my code to that project, the app started running successfully through Eclipse.

The thing that I did wrong was that I started with a `Dynamic Web project` in Eclipse, added my code and then converted to a spring boot project through spring-boot-starter dependencies (`spring-boot-starter`, `spring-boot-starter-web`) in `pom.xml`

But Eclipse was not recognizing that as a Spring boot application. May be you can try to create a new `Spring Boot Starter project` and migrate your code into that and try running from Eclipse.

**NOTE :** I used `Spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE` and the embedded Tomcat version without overriding it i.e. `8.5.23` and `Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0`